# How can I display a backtick inside the \texttt environment?

Tags: typewriter

I am building an automatic password generator producing a pdf. 
I am having troubles in typesetting the backticks, how can I print a backtick in inside a \texttt?

EDIT: my mac spell checker changed backtick to backpack in the title, now I corrected it

Comment: `\texttt{\`abc}`  or do you mean you are looking for a straighter left quote?

Comment: I would like to print a real backtick

Comment: Please define `real'

Answer (score 12):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\begin{document}

\texttt{`abc \textasciigrave abc}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8):

I have found also that I can also use `` \`{} ``

Answer (score 1):

For those using the `listings` package instead of just `\texttt`, you can add the following line to either `\lstdefinelanguage` or `\lstset`:

```
literate={`}{\textasciigrave}1,
```

For example, here is my `\lstdefinelanguage` for PVS:

```
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\definecolor{darkblue}{rgb}{0,0,0.6}
\definecolor{darkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.5,0}
\definecolor{darkred}{rgb}{0.6,0,0}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstdefinelanguage{pvs}{
  basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
  keywordstyle=\color{darkblue}\bfseries,
  morekeywords={and,andthen,array,assuming,assumption,auto_rewrite,auto_rewrite+,auto_rewrite-,axiom,begin,but,by,cases,challenge,claim,closure,cond,
                conjecture,containing,conversion,conversion+,conversion-,corollary,datatype,else,elsif,end,endassuming,endcases,endcond,endif,endtable,exists,exporting,
                fact,false,forall,formula,from,function,has_type,if,iff,implies,importing,in,inductive,judgement,lambda,law,lemma,
                let,library,macro,measure,nonempty_type,not,o,obligation,of,or,orelse,postulate,proposition,recursive,sublemma,subtypes,subtype_of,
                table,then,theorem,theory,true,type,type+,var,when,where,with,xor},
  sensitive=false,
  literate={`}{\textasciigrave}1,
  commentstyle=\color{darkgreen},
  morecomment=[l]{\%},
  stringstyle=\color{darkred},
  morestring=[b]",
}
```

If you're using a [known language](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/listings/listings.pdf) (e.g., C), you can just do:

```
\lstset{% 
  language=C,
  literate={`}{\textasciigrave}1,
}
```

This will use the substitution suggested by [David Carlisle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/420073/5646) everywhere you use the backtick in your code listing. I then define a command called `\code` for doing in-line code using the `listings` package:

```
\newcommand{\code}[1]{\lstinline{#1}}
```

So I can then just use `` \code{`abc} `` to get the result you want.